# Unreal Engine and Clion (Cannot get compiler information)

Tags: c++, clion, unreal-engine4

I've set up my unreal engine to use Clion as it's text-editor by enabling the Clion extension.
And also downloaded Unreal Engine extension within the Clion market.

When I click on Generate and Open Clion in Unreal Engine Editor, it opens the clion, it takes a few moments for loading the project, and then throws an error saying "Cannot get compiler information".

since I Use MinGW to compile my C++ codes, I Thought there might be a problem with the compiler, So I changed the compiler to Visual Studio as you'll see in the following images, but still getting the same error.

Here's the error that I'm getting:

```
Cannot get compiler information:
Compiler exited with error code 2: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx86\x86\cl.exe" @C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\response-file16483339914833625835 C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\compiler-file6661270899180288812 | @response-file16483339914833625835=/TP -DACTORLAYERUTILITIESEDITOR_API= -DACTORLAYERUTILITIESEDITOR_VTABLE=DLLEXPORT_VTABLE
```

since the error is extremely long, 786000 characters and to my unprofessional eyes, only the first few lines are useful, I'll put the first few lines in here and put the rest in a text file.

full error in a text file: https://gofile.io/?c=WSlII1

Please tell me if you need more information, Thanks in advance

[image]
[image][image]

Comment: Maybe you find something useful in here: https://github.com/dotBunny/CLionSourceCodeAccess/issues/35

Comment: @infinitezero Yes, I found something useful in there! Thank you for sharing the link.

Comment: In that case you may answer your own question here on this site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem.

Here's my solution:

1. In UE editor, click on File, click on Open Clion to open your project in Clion.
2. In the Clion, Click on File -> Setting -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Toolchains, and Set the Visual Studio as the environment compiler. (in my case vs 2017 community)
3. File -> Setting -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> CMake, Change the Build type from Debug to Release.

If this fixed your problem but you got some strange error afterward, that might be because of CMake caches, to fix that one, Click on Tools -> CMake -> Reset Cache and Reload Project.

Hope this helps someone.